# Asp.Net MVC : File upload does not work on some machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strange situation - in my ASP.NET MVC web app there is file upload control. When I upload in production, it works fine from some PCs but gives a 404 error from others.

I've tried with same file (20 kb) from two different machines but again from one machine it works from another it does not.

I would be grateful for any suggestions as to what might be the cause of this.

Comment: 404 Means the page was not found.
Check the URL being used in the upload.

Comment: yes..i checked it is uploaded